# Need Advise for the best Fundraising Plugin

Tags: wordpress

Hi I need advise what is the best plugin that make user ( not admin ) to be able to make their own campaign fundraising in WordPress ?

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read about this below plugin:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/personal-fundraiser/
https://wordpress.org/plugins/charitable/

Comment: I'm going to try this one https://premium.wpmudev.org/project/wordpress-fundraising/ . What do you think about it Mohod Sandhya

Comment: Yes, This is also good plugin but first please try it's free trial version then after purchase it.